# Single Stage Transistor Amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, sound, gain

so I have a question to build a single stage transisitor amplifier. I know Rc/Re = gain. And the value of capacitor which is parallel to Re can be found by the formula F = 1/2piRC but I have difficulties in finding values of other resistances because there are 4 resistances in the circuit, and i only know 2. Can you explain how to get another 2 values? 
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should know that for a common emitter stage the simple gain expression Rc/Re is a rough approximation only. More than that (because you mention a capacitor Ce across Re), this expression does NOT apply if Re is bypassed with Ce (for frequencies higher than the corresponding cut-off frequency).

Secondly, it is common practice to bias the base with a well-dimensioned voltage divider. Suitable resistor values are derived from a trade-off: The resistive level should (a) as low as possible in order to produce a "stiff" DC voltage (relatively independent on the DC base current Ib and its large tolerances) and (b) not too low because of power consumption and a sufficiently high signal input resistance.

For this reason, it is common practice to allow a DC current through this resistive divider which is approximately I=nIb with n=(6...10).

Comment: I still dont quite understand why do we need the voltage divider? could you explain more? I already edited the post and added schematic diagram. I want to have a gain at least 60 V/V. this is a sound amplification  and also it requires low frequency 3dB should be less than 100Hz. Im still confused how to get started since you said Rc/Re is just rough estimation? so what I should do first? thanks

Comment: Do you know how and why a transistor-based amplifier works? Do you know why we need DC biasing?

Comment: If you do not know how a transistor works it will be not easy for you to design an amplifying stage. Sorry to say.

Comment: do you have any good reference that i can read or understand about designing an amplifying stage? sorry. im quite new in this course. im a first year student. hope you dont mind teaching me. I know we need to bias the Dc current so we can have Vb right? thanks

Comment: There are many many books and many contributions in the internet about basics of electronics. I think, you should start a search by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your requirements, frequency range, and supply voltage.

For a simple circuit, you choose the base resistors to bias the transistor sufficiently -- generally values that are 10 to 100x the emitter resistance are a good starting point -- but you have to provide a schematic to have a more detailed answer.

Comment: so i want to build a circuit with a gain of at least 60 V/V , im using Q2N3904, i decided to make two gain of 9, so total 9X 9 =81 . this is a sound amplification, and it requires "Your low frequency 3dB should be less than 100Hz." i already edited the post with schematic so i can get detailed help. thanks

Comment: Still not enough info. Your 'Amplification' block needs more than 1 transistor to bias the output stage properly

Comment: why we need more than 1 transistor? Can  you explain more?

Comment: Because the 2 output transistors are biased off and you have no feedback from the output. Basically, your output will be zero until signal levels exceed + and - 0.7 V.

Comment: so do for the first transistor, I need to set Vb (voltage at the base) first right? lets say I set it to 1.1V, and find the ratio of R1 and R2 using voltage divider right?  Then, we can find the Ib, Ic, Ie, right? Thank you for helping me out because some people dont want to explain more about it.  really appreciate it!